# How to remove TabPage from TabControl?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to remove a particular tabpage from the tabcontrol. For which i have the value of tab name which has to be closed.

But, when i use..

```
for (int i = 0; i < myTabControl.TabPages.Count; i++)
{
    if (myTabControl.TabPages[i].Name.Equals(tabToRemove, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        myTabControl.TabPages.RemoveAt(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

It is not going inside the loop because the count is zero.
whereas the the tabcontrol is visible with two tabs in it.

whats the problem ?

This is how i am adding the tabs ->

```
public void TabIt(string strProcessName)
{
    this.Show();

    //Creating MDI child form and initialize its fields
    MDIChild childForm = new MDIChild();
    childForm.Text = strProcessName;
    childForm.MdiParent = this;

    //child Form will now hold a reference value to the tab control
    childForm.TabCtrl = tabControl1;

    //Add a Tabpage and enables it
    TabPage tp = new TabPage();

    tp.Parent = tabControl1;
    tp.Text = childForm.Text;
    tp.Show();
    //child Form will now hold a reference value to a tabpage
    childForm.TabPag = tp;
    //Activate the MDI child form
    childForm.Show();
    childCount++;

    //Activate the newly created Tabpage.
    tabControl1.SelectedTab = tp;
    tabControl1.ItemSize = new Size(200, 32);
    tp.Height = tp.Parent.Height;
    tp.Width = tp.Parent.Width;
}


public void GetTabNames()
{

    foreach (string strProcessName in Global.TabProcessNames)
    {
        TabIt(strProcessName);
    }
}
```

---

The child form :

```
using System; using System.Drawing; using System.Collections; using System.ComponentModel; using System.Windows.Forms; using System.Data; using System.Diagnostics; using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace Daemon 
{ 

public class MDIChild : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.Container components = null;
    private TabControl tabCtrl;
    private TabPage tabPag;

    public MDIChild()
    {
            //
            // Required for Windows Form Designer support
            //
            InitializeComponent();
    //MDIChild TargerForm = new MDIChild();
    //WinApi.SetWinFullScreen(TargerForm.Handle); 
            //
            // TODO: Add any constructor code after InitializeComponent call
            //
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
    {
            if( disposing )
            {
                    if(components != null)
                    {
                            components.Dispose();
                    }
            }
            base.Dispose( disposing );
    }

    public TabPage TabPag
    {
            get
            {
                    return tabPag;
            }
            set
            {
                    tabPag = value;
            }
    }

    public TabControl TabCtrl
    {
            set
            {
                    tabCtrl = value;
            }
    }


    #region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // MDIChild
    // 
    this.AutoScaleBaseSize = new System.Drawing.Size(5, 13);
    this.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
    this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.InactiveCaptionText;
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 0);
    this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
    this.MaximizeBox = false;
    this.MinimizeBox = false;
    this.Name = "MDIChild";
    this.Opacity = 0;
    this.ShowIcon = false;
    this.SizeGripStyle = System.Windows.Forms.SizeGripStyle.Hide;
    this.Text = "MDIChild"; 
    this.Activated += new System.EventHandler(this.MDIChild_Activated);
    this.Closing += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.MDIChild_Closing);
    this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
    #endregion

    private void MDIChild_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
    try
    {
        //Destroy the corresponding Tabpage when closing MDI child form
        this.tabPag.Dispose();

        //If no Tabpage left
        if (!tabCtrl.HasChildren)
        {
            tabCtrl.Visible = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
    }
    }

    private void MDIChild_Activated(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    try
    {
        //Activate the corresponding Tabpage
        tabCtrl.SelectedTab = tabPag;

        if (!tabCtrl.Visible)
        {
            tabCtrl.Visible = true;
        }
        Global.ExistingTabProcessNames.Add(tabPag.Text);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
    }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Where are you executing this statement ? In Page_Load ? Maybe the control has not been initialized correctly. Are you sure that the tabcontrol is wired with the myTabControl member variable ?

Comment: I am not executing in pageload. Its a separate function. 

what to do ?

Comment: You might want to post the code to how youre adding the tagpages, since the problem is before this code if TabPages.Count is zero

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the name of the TabPage what is wrong with doing just this...

```
tabControl1.TabPages.RemoveByKey("tabPage1");
```

?

Comment: Tried the above.. No errors.. But it is not removing the tab.

Comment: Yes it is correct.
Anyway, The tabcontrol shows like tabpages.count = o when i debug

Comment: If the count is zero then i guess the tab pages are not being added correctly.

Comment: If the tabpages are not added properly, then how do i get the tabpages.
I have already added the tabpages. Now the problem is with removing the tab from tabcontrol.

Comment: Put some code up showing how you are adding the controls. There could be an issue at that point.

Comment: @karthik - it doesn't look like you are adding the TagPage to the TabControl. After you create your TabPage item, you need to do something like tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp);

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, Anuya, without the whole code, it's hard to tell which of these may or may not be useful to you, but here's three ideas or thoughts you may consider:

1st consideration:

when you are adding the TabPages to the TabControl, i notice that you seem to not really be adding it to the TabControl's Controls collection. I truly think you may need to add `tabControl1.Controls.Add(tp);` when you are adding the TabPage to really add it to the TabControl's 'Count' of TabPages.

2nd consideration:

i am unaware that calling TabPage.Dispose will remove a TabPage from a TabControl, but maybe it will work. When i remove TabPages, i use the TabControl.Remove() method.

3rd consideration:

i had some TabControl problems and the only way i solved it was add a timer to my project and then at the next timer tick, do something. so i ended up writing my own action processor with different actions i could do and i had an action list with a timestamp for when that action should be processed. the action list ended up being very useful for many things, but i first needed it for my TabControl. in my case, i needed to show a tab page, but when i added a TabPage, it did not display correctly even when i set the selected tab page after adding it. But when i selected the tab page that i wanted about 100 ms after i added the tab page, it worked flawlessly, with one slight ugly: the tab control 'blinks'. That is the user can see the tab page flicker since it actually draws the newly added tab page, then 100 ms later it selects the tab page that i want. but it was the only way i solved my problem. i wonder if your issue might be related to mine, where maybe you can remove the tab page 100 ms after you are trying to do it now.

Those are three considerations, of which i suspect my first option might solve your first problem.

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 1):

While your code adds the tabpage to the form as you would add any control, it does not add the tabpage to the TabPages collection of the TabControl, that's why you don't find it later.

Add a tab page like below, so it will show up in the TabPages collection:

```
    // helper - create a new tabpage
    static private TabPage _AddTabPage( TabControl tabControl, string caption )
    {
        int pageIndex = tabControl.TabPages.Count;
        tabControl.TabPages.Add(caption);
        return tabControl.TabPages[pageIndex];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        foreach(TabPage page in tabctr.TabPages)
        {
            if (page.Name == "tabPage2")
            {
                tabctr.TabPages.Remove(page);
            }
        }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) helps to improve the quality of your response. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.