# Why doesn't this LINQ Query Work?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I was attempting to help someone else out and wrote this query:

```
var foundTab = (from tab in tabControl1.TabPages
                where tab.Name == "tabName"
                select tab).First();
```

And they reported that they received this error:

> Could not find an implementation of
>   the query pattern for source type
>   System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.TabPageCollection'.
>   'Where' not found. Consider explicitly
>   specifying the type of the range
>   variable 'tab'.

I checked MSDN and `TabPageCollection` implements `IList`, `ICollection`, `IEnumerable`. So, what's going on here? What does that error mean and is there another way to query the Tab Control's `TabPages` property?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
var tab = (from System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tab in tabControl1.TabPages
           where tab.Name == "tabName"
           select tab).First();
```

This code specifies the type of the range variable.

Comment: Looks a little cleaner than the cast method. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`TabPageCollection` implements `IEnumerable` but not `IEnumerable<T>` which is what LINQ uses. To fix, use the cast method like so:

```
var foundTab = (from tab in tabControl1.TabPages.Cast<TabPage>()
            where tab.Name == "tabName"
            select tab).First();
```

Comment: Besides the original mistakes I made ("tab" twice and I forgot the select clause, I'm surprised no one noticed, LOL!), this works perfectly. Thanks for mentioning the `IEnumerable`/`IEnumerable<T>` explanation.

Comment: Error : Aquery body must end with a select or group clause

Answer (score 2):

But, but but....?  you  could just reference it directly if you have the name?  TabPages["tabname"]

Comment: I've been programming for 20 years, did LINQ before you were out of diapers fool. worked on Microsoft's Premier .NET team. Hush yourself fool ! ( LOL - just having fun ) :)  and if you ever endured a Microsoft interview they would yell at you for using the overhead of LINQ ( whIch I love ) instead of just indexing into the tabpages indexer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var tab = tabControl1.TabPages.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == "tabName");
```

Also, make sure you have

```
using System.Linq;
```

at the top of your file.

Dylan